# Mongoose how to get a object length?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I wanto to get a length of an object using the mongoose lib

here is my code

```
const mongo = require("../../server") // model call
    
     {...}
    
    var query = 'email@email.com'; //get an email
        var db = mongo.connection;
        
        db.db.collection("user").findOne({email:query}, function(err, result) {
    
          if (err) throw err; 
          if ( result.length > 0) {...} // here I want to get my object length
```

In result.length Im getting an error because there's no length in my object , so someone know's how can I get it ?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava No , I tried what the answer says to put an Object.size(OBJECT), but it says that object.size is not a function

Comment: Read on further in the answer..

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava I found it , I got the answer using Object.values(MYOBJECT).length thanks for coming by

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys(result).length` to get the length of entries

Comment: This one was returning me a keys is not a function , but I used a Object.values(MYOBJECT).length and it worked , but thanks for coming by

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked but its strange why Object.keys didn't work as Object prototype has both of these methods